# Completeness of normal sample values

Tags: self-study, inference, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

I have a small query. We know that sample values are always sufficient. Can we say the same for completeness property?

Let us say I have $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ following $N(0, \sigma^2)$. Hence, if we take an estimator $T(X) = (X_1, X_2,.., X_n)$ Can I say that this sample is complete? I can show that by factorization that $T(X)$ is a sufficient statistic while for knowing the completeness, I go like this.

Let me take $g(T(X)) = \sum x_i$. Now, this function will follow $N(0, 2n\sigma^2)$. Clearly, I can find an unbiased estimate of $0$ which is a function of our desired statistic because $E(g(T(X)) = 0$. Hence, can I conclude from here that the sample values are not complete?

Comment: Can we take just two points from the sample to make a function of statistic?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/510179/minimal-sufficient-statistic-of-normal-with-known-variance, in this answer you mentioned that $T_2 = (\bar{X}, S^2) $ can't be considered as a function of $T_1 = (\bar{X})$. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to spell out the complete argument, consider the transform
\begin{align*}\Psi:& \qquad\mathbb R^n \quad\longmapsto \quad\mathbb R\\
&(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto x_1-x_2
\end{align*}
Then $\mathbb E[\Psi(X_1,\ldots,X_n)]=\mathbb E[X_1-X_2]=0$ and the iid sample $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ cannot be complete since $\Psi(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a non-zero function with zero expectation for all values of the parameter.

In the specific Normal illustration, $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ cannot be complete since the transform$$\Psi(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\sum X_i$$has a zero expectation for all values of $\sigma$.

Comment: @Xian, I understand this and I understood you earlier also (when you commented). But what I was trying to say is that what you seem to be doing is making a function with transformation from n dimension to one dimension. Now, I have no doubt in this point. But, Can i do the same to make a function of $T_2 = (\bar{X},S^2) $. Like on a similar line like you did, can I define a transformation like this :  $\begin{align*}\Psi:& \qquad\mathbb R^n \quad\longmapsto \quad\mathbb R\\
&(\bar{X},S^2) \mapsto \bar{X}
\end{align*}$

Comment: Sorry,@xian. All this while, i was thinking something else but now i got your point.